# Can't open QImage source file

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm currently building a small project in Qt and wanted to import an icon. I made folder (icons) and put my icon there. Then I made a duplicate of the qml.qrc and changed it, so it contains my resource.

```
<RCC>
    <qresource>
        <file>icons/projectfoldericon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

However, when I set my image as the source of an QImage, it always fails, saying that it can't find the image. The image is loaded properly if I click it in the QtEditor. For the image path, I also tried `/icons/projectfoldericon.png`, and `:/icons/projectfoldericon.png`. Any idea what's causing the problem here?

[image: In the middle you can see the place where I add the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="projectfoldericon.png">icons/projectfoldericon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And in your .qml file :

```
source: "projectfoldericon.png"
```

Don't forget that each time you make changes on your files listed in the QRC file, you need to use `qmake` on the .qrc file.

Comment: Didn't know about the qmake part. Thanks, that solved it! (I'll accept the answer when the three minutes are over)

Comment: Yeah, I used to forget it everytime and wondered why it wasn't working... Just need to make it a habit :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the image in Qt Creator and click the Copy Path "....",

now, your image source path is on the clipboard, you can paste it to code.

or you can use url with click the Copy url "...." and use it to same way.

build it before using the image after the added image to resource file

[image]